# Organizing Images and their thumnails

Tags: image, structure, photos

What's the best-practice method of storing a user's uploaded pictures and it's corresponding thumbnails. I noticed Flickr uses filename distinctions like: `http://farm5.static.flickr.com/1234/789456123a_s.jpg` where `_s.jpg` describes the size of the image (_s.jpg = small, _m.jpg = medium...). However, does storing images like the following make sense?

`/images/123456.jpg`
`/images/small/123456.jpg`
`/images/medium/123456.jpg`

...therefore, it's easy to access different sizes by simply pre-pending the folder-size name

Answer (score 1):

Whatever works for you - pick a scheme and stick to it. As long as you're consistent, and document what you do, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanx. Do you think it's necessary to add thumbnail information to the database? Or, is it enough to know the path to the original and then pre-pend folder names to get its thumbnail?

Comment: Depends on the scheme you pick, but generally, I'd prefer a scheme where the path and filename of the thumbnail can be deduced from the original filename, and doesn't need to be stored explicitly. Avoids redundancy.